# Pine Script v.5 error: “Could not find function or function reference 'macd'”

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am not a programmer and struggling through Pine Script v.5.

I have a Bollinger band indicator which uses as its source the MACD histogram.

I am trying to code a strategy that, when the histogram is below the zero line, tells me to buy at the close of the first bar where the distance of the lower band in relation to the zero line decreases more than distance between the edge of the histogram and the zero line.

When the histogram is above the zero line, I want the strategy to tell me to sell at the close of the first bar where the distance of the upper band in relation to the zero line decreases more than distance between the upper edge of the histogram and the zero line.

I am trying to use the following code for this strategy and getting this error “Could not find function or function reference 'macd'”.  Anyone have any thoughts?  Your input is greatly appreciated.

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bollinger Band Indicator", overlay=true)

// Define inputs
source = input(close, title="Source")
length = input(20, title="Length")
mult = input(2.0, title="Multiplier")

// Define MACD histogram
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = macd(source)

// Define Bollinger Bands
basis = sma(source, length)
dev = mult * stdev(source, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

// Define zero line
zeroLine = hline(0)

// Define buy and sell signals
buySignal = histLine < zeroLine and lower - zeroLine < zeroLine - histLine
sellSignal = histLine > zeroLine and upper - zeroLine > zeroLine - histLine

// Execute trades
    if buySignal
strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
    if sellSignal
strategy.entry("Sell", strategy.short)

// Plot Bollinger Bands and MACD histogram    
plot(basis)
plot(upper)
plot(lower)
plot(histLine)
```

I tried making changes to how I reference MACD, but as a non-programmer I am probably just making a basic mistake that I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the ta name space in front of the macd. You need to put in the rest of the parameters too for the macd, (source, fast length, slow length, signal length) You’ll need to do the same ta namespace  for the basis sma too.

```
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(source)
```